# Sandstorm - postgresql not running

Tags: django, postgresql, sandstorm.io

I'm trying to port `sayIt`, a django app with postgresql as a sandstorm app.

I have an instance running on Ubuntu, and using raw packaging to run it in dev mode. However, an error occurs as below:

```
...** SANDSTORM SUPERVISOR: Starting up grain. Sandbox type: userns
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 168, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 191, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried to enter the grain, but the document just says read vagrant-spk's source code which I read but can't understand.

It seems like postgresql is not running and listening, but I totally have no idea why. Any hint is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you see if postgresql is actually running? `ps -ef` look for `postmaster`

Comment: I try to `ps -ef` in `launcher.sh` but it says `Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc`, and if I enter this it says needs `sudo`, then if I `sudo` it says NO.

Comment: Does your launcher.sh start postgres? If not, it won't be running...

Comment: I thought django will run postgresql. I try to start postgresql in `launcher.sh`, but it seems like more trick needed here. I need to find what's the correct command to start postgres.

Comment: I really need a bash into the grain to find where are the files I need to write in `launcher.sh`. Can anyone teach me how to? :/

Comment: Have you seen [this forum topic](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sandstorm-dev/Z1ISwj1ytXk/discussion) dealing with how to start postgresql in a grain?

Comment: @harmic Thank you, I'll read it.

Comment: I tried that post then hang by `FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" must be owned by the database user or root`, I don't know how to solve this because when I try to `chmod`, it says `Invalid user: root` :/